# Custom tags on Microsoft clarity

Tags: javascript, angular, ms-clarity

I want to add a custom tag on ms clarity for a particular click event for eg-: (i want to track the users clicking cancel button), so that it should only fire when a user click on the cancel button,i am on an angular project. How can i do that ?

i tried putting script tags on the html page of the component which contains cancel button and passed the button id using addEventListener, but that button already has a normal click function :/

Answer (score 0):

When we want to do some in a severals elements a Directive (with a selector) go to rescuest

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'button[type=cancel]'
})
export class BtCancelDirective {
  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])click(btn)
  {
    console.log(btn,btn.getAttribute('id'))
  }
}
```

So you can use

```
<button id="one" type="cancel">click</button>
```

Well, you can use another selectors like `button:not([type=submit]),button:not([type=button])` or another you can imagine

To know more about selector I like this [link in medium](https://medium.com/swlh/anatomy-of-angular-attribute-directive-selector-a1d83a73242) or the [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector)

Comment: These Ms clarity tracking code only works on head part of the project which is index.html, so from there we have to add the custom tag for this specific button click which is on another component.